# Is unsafe C# garbage collected

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I was reading about memory leaks in managed code and wondered if it was possible to create this in C# unsafe code?

```
unsafe
{
    while(true) new int; 
}
```

I wasn't sure if this would be caught by the GC if this was running as unsafe code?

Thanks

Comment: I like how every keyword in that code snippet is highlighted blue.

Comment: This won't compile; it's missing parentheses.  Also, `int` is a bad example, because it's a value type.

Comment: +1 This seems like a reasonable question. Why the down votes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `unsafe` keyword just allows you to use unsafe code (pointers).

It doesn't change the semantics of ordinary code at all.

Answer (score 8):

IMO unsafe only permits to use pointer types and proform C++ style pointer opeartion on memory. But to tell garbage collector not touch my code use **fixed** statement.

C# supports direct memory manipulation via pointers within blocks of code marked
unsafe and compiled with the /unsafe compiler option.

The **fixed** statement is used to tell the garbage collector to not touch that code that was rounded with **fixed** statement

```
   unsafe
    {
       fixed (int* a = &b)   // tells garbage collector not touch 
       {
         *a = 9;
       }    
    }
```